# reverting the changes when multiple clicks on same div

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a div mapped so it would render any number of times according to data sent from the database. I'm setting a background color in the div when clicking on the div. How can i revert the changes if i click the div again?

**My code**

```
handleClick(id) {

let el = document.getElementById(id);

        if (el) {

            el.style.backgroundColor = "#0b97c4";
            el.style.color = "#FFFFFF";

            this.setState({

                voteCount: this.state.voteCount + 1

            })
        }

        this.props.submitvote(vote_object)

}

render() {

        let {contents, submitvote, postId, voted_id} = this.props

        return (

            <div className="txt_vote_bar_div" id={this.props.contents.post_poll_content_id}>
                <p className="txt_vote_choice" id={this.props.contents.post_poll_content_id}
                onClick={() => {this.handleClick(this.props.contents.post_poll_content_id);}}>
                    {contents.content}
                </p>
                <p className="txt_tot_votes"> {this.props.contents.votes_percentage}%
                ({this.state.voteCount} Votes)
                </p>
            </div>
        );
    };
```

using the above code i'm changing the background of the div successfully. How can i remove the background color if i select the same div again (remove background color or change it to another color)

Answer (score 0):

I would make `txt_vote_choice` "old" CSS name, and `txt_vote_clicked` is new `className` that you want to change. By `onClick`, toggle the `className` between these 2 classes would do the trick.

```html
handleClick(id) {
  let el = document.getElementById(id);
  if (el) {
    if el.class == "txt_vote_choice" ? "txt_vote_clicked": "txt_vote_choice";

    this.setState({
      voteCount: this.state.voteCount + 1
    })
  }

  this.props.submitvote(vote_object)
}

render() {

  let {contents, submitvote, postId, voted_id, voted_css} = this.props

  return (
    <div  className="txt_vote_bar_div"
          id={this.props.contents.post_poll_content_id}>
      <p  className={voted_css}
          id={this.props.contents.post_poll_content_id}
          onClick={() => {this.handleClick(this.props.contents.post_poll_content_id);}}>
        {contents.content}
      </p>
      <p className="txt_tot_votes"> 
        {this.props.contents.votes_percentage}%({this.state.voteCount} Votes)
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Then update the CSS accordingly

Comment: if i switch classNames using states every div gets the backgroundColor

Comment: Then can use another additional `className` for your desired element ?

Comment: your code snippet is not working.can you please fix it so i can take an idea about your solution?

Answer (score 0):

if it is just an "on-off" feature, you can check for the "active" style already on your div like this : `if (el.style.backgroundColor == "#0b97c4";) //if the style is already there:` then you run some code that put your div the right color

```
if (el)
{
    if (el.style.backgroundColor == "#0b97c4";) //if the style is already there:
    {
        el.style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
        el.style.color = "#000000"; //put theese 2 colors to the "unactivated" ones

        //other code when you unselect goes here like this.state.voteCount - 1
    }
    else
    {
        el.style.backgroundColor = "#0b97c4";
        el.style.color = "#FFFFFF";

        this.setState({
            voteCount: this.state.voteCount + 1
        })
    }
}
```